# Python binary file write directly from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, png

I have the byte-code of a png-file in a string variable. How do I write it to .png file without python trying to encode it? The string is '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xceK4\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x00DIDAT\x18Wc\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xaf\xfd\x07\xdf[:\xbc\x95Q\x81  \xfb\xc7\xaa\xb5@q \x00I#\xcb\xc1\x11D\x11H\xfa\xdb\x94\x19hr\x10\xf4NY\x1b$\x8d\x0c\x90\x95~\xad\xacE\x97F\x03\x94H\xff\xff\x0f\x00\x1f]\xa2\x03U|Z\xa3\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

edit: I feel like you might need more info on my situation: I am trying to make a little encryption program, and although it works on strings, I want to make it work for any file too. I am reading a .png file in byte-mode(which gives the string mentioned above), and after it is done being encrypted and decrypted, I have a string with the exact same content, but no way to put it back into a file.

Comment: open the file in binary mode (use 'wb' instead of 'w')

Comment: Why aren't you using a `bytes` object, instead of a `str`, which in Python 3 is sequence of unicode code points. In other words, how did you create this `str`?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy almost certainly, the OP desires a bytes object that is being represented by the *string*. I.e. the bytes object that would be created by pre-pending that string literal with a `b`

Comment: Thanks John, unfortunately I have tried it, with no avail.

Comment: juanpa, I need to do things like finding parts of it etc., some of whick is only possible on a string. Do you know of any way to convert the string back to it's prior type?

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis what exactly isn't possible with a `bytes` object that is possible with a `str`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, If you look at my edit to the question you might understand, but just in case:

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis but if you are reading it in `binary` mode, then it *doesn't return a `str`, it returns a `bytes` object*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have to convert the original to different types as part of my algorithim, from which the output will have to be a string, as I use parts of other strings to build it up.

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis **why are you using strings**? You should be sticking *only with bytes*. As soon as you use `str`, you are complicating your life. You almost certainly can stick to using `bytes` objects. They can do almost everything `str` can do, indeed, `bytes` is *equivalent to Python 2 `str`*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that would require a rewrite of my algorithim, which I would obviosly like to avoid. So if there is any other way I would be grateful, otherwise I'll start later, since it 2 o clock here

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis *how* would it? It very likely would only require you to append a few `b`s to some string literals making them bytes literals. Again, *why are you using strings when you want bytes*?

Comment: Fundamentally, you aren't grokking the difference between the `str` and `bytes` datatypes. You say that after your processing, you begin with a `bytes` object and end up with "a string with the exact same content" but that doesn't make any sense. At some point, you `decode` your bytes object into a `str` using some codec, so you now have a sequence of Unicode code points. That is **not** the exact same content. Presumably, you should be able to encode it with whatever codec you used to decode the original `bytes`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What you say makes sense, only I never ecplicitly told python to decode anything, so now I have to figure outh with what codec python did it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For python3, you have to open the file in binary write mode **and** encode the string to bytes:

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(the_string.encode())
```

Comment: But *encoding* is precisely what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: I though he meant without python converting the bytes (ascii) to utf characters, or escaping backslashes

Comment: *what do you think `.encode()` does?* In other words, what you are doing here is essentially equivalent to opening in text mode and writing the `str` directly.

Comment: I have tried opening it in wb and rb mode, but that forces me to convert it. I read the string from above from the file, as bytearray, but I need to perform actions on it only possible with a string, but is there any way then to take that string and revert it to the type it was previously?

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis revert it back to byte array?

Comment: @jacoblaw that requires encoding it, which screws it up

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis I meant in your comment above mine, you say "but is there any way then to take that string and revert it to the type it was previously?". What type was it previously? You take in a byte array somewhere, turn it into a string to manipulate, then want to write this string representation of the bytes of your png to a new .png, right?

Comment: @jacoblaw , sounds about right, although I fail to understand which encoding would make it work. And also I assume this won't work with all filetypes?

Comment: @JeanDuPlessis also, what is an example of an action only possible with `str` and not `bytes` in your algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using PyPNG, looks like a possible solution:
http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html#writing

This will let you write binary to a file in python.

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(bytecode)
```

Comment: This won't work. `f.write` will requires a `bytes` object, but the OP has a `str`

Comment: Yep forgot to put encode, should I just delete this answer since it is essentially the same as above?

Comment: @J.Clark I don't think either is what the OP wants. The OP wants to write the *bytes represented by the string* to the file. If you `encode` it, it will *change the bytes*. The underlying problem for the OP, as I see it, is *why* is this in a `str` and not a `bytes` object?

Comment: @J.Clark, If you want to. Thanks for trying